# redirect any subdomain to a servlet using a wildcard expression using jboss wildfly 10

Tags: servlets, jboss, wildfly-10

We have multiple member accounts signing up. what we want is to provide a subdomain for each member which would take them to their own little world....

eg: memberOne.myapp.com
eg: memberTwo.myapp.com

The only configuration i could come up with so far is the following

```
<host name="myappname" alias="memberOne.myapp.com, memberTwo.myapp.com>
    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
</host>
```

and then add in a jboss-web.xml entry.

Of course this is not the ideal solution because i would have to manually add these member accounts into the standalone.xml file

Is there any possible solution to use a wildcard expression to redirect any subdomain to a particular servlet.

eg: *.myapp.com ---> myapp/controller

Comment: Tryed you with `alias="*.myapp.com"`?